# Django junction table with extra foreignkey

Tags: python, sql, django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have the following models

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Any text to describe a company'
    )
    url = models.URLField('company URL', blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('date created', default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'company'
        verbose_name_plural = 'companies'
        ordering = ['name', '-created_on']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Company {0.name}>'.format(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Any text to describe the project'
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('date created', default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'project'
        verbose_name_plural = 'projects'
        ordering = ['-created_on', 'company']
        permissions = (
            ("can_view_project",
             "Can view all project related work"),
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Project {0.name}>'.format(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Worker(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Optional. Describe what the worker does or who they are'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'user'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Worker {0.id}'.format(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_fullname()
```

### The problem

I would like to add a ManyToMany relationship between `Project` and `Worker` so that I can view
a list of workers under a certain project. However, I want to make sure that a worker can only
be added to a project if they are both part of the same company.

I was planning on using a junction table with a ForeignKey to both of their company attributes,
but according to the django docs, a foreignkey can only be used once per model
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

How do I make sure that the many to many relationship between the two tables is limited to the same company?

Is there perhaps another way to ensure that workers cannot work on projects outside of their own company?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you define the many to many relationship this way in the `Project` model:

```
workers = ManyToManyField(Worker)
```

Assuming you have a model form named `ProjectForm` to create or modify projects. You can define a `clean` function in this form:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ProjectForm, self).clean()
    for w in cleaned_data['workers']:
        if w.company.id != cleaned_data['company'].id:
              self.add_error('workers', your_error_message)
              break
    return cleaned_data
```

Hope this help.